# Why Lambda expression parameter appears in method parameter list?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, roslyn

I am trying to get the parameters list of a class method using Roslyn and noticed a strange behavior that Roslyn considers and returns a Lambda parameter used inside the body of the method as as one of the parameters of the method, which cause an error in my code. Why does Roslyn consider a lambda parameter as of the method's parameters?

Here is the code:

```
var paramDeclaratons = memmeth.DescendantNodes().OfType<ParameterSyntax>();
foreach (var mempara in paramDeclaratons)
{                            
    String paramType = mempara.Type.ToFullString().Trim(); //Here it crashes with System.NullReferenceException because Lambda returns no type!
```

The code which is parsed:

```
public void Method1(RequestId requestId)
{
     ...
     var packetsToKeep = this.queuedPackets.Where(p => p.RequestId != requestId)
```

p is returned as one of the parameters of Method1 with no type

Comment: Crashes how? Which exception is thrown?

Comment: Throws System.NullReferenceException

Comment: ```mempara.Type.ToFullString()?.Trim();``` I would suggest you use nullpropagation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Because `p => p.RequestId != requestId` is a lambda, and you asked for *all* descendant nodes of the method...

Comment: Roslyn is not claiming that `p` is a parameter to your method, it is claiming that `p` is a parameter to something that is a descendant of your `memmeth`. That's what you asked for. As to why `.Type` is `null` in this case I don't know, you will have to check the documentation.

Comment: I was wondering that maybe <ParameterSyntax> is not the right type then for only getting method parameters. Maybe there is another type I should use here for that purpose?

Comment: "Sometimes it is difficult or impossible for the compiler to infer the input types." So you can always give the parameter a type.
This is explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions

Comment: Guys, I edited the question and removed the part I wrote on how to handle the NullReferenceException error. I was more curious about if I should use another type instead of <ParameterSyntax> to only get method's parameters and noticed many people referred me to general solutions for handling NullReferenceException and down-voted my question. To avoid this confusion I removed that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `memmeth` is a `MethodDeclarationSyntax`, then what you want is to access its `ParameterList.Parameters`:

```
var paramDeclaratons = memmeth.ParameterList.Parameters;
```

Comment: Thanks, that made all the difference!

Comment: How to declare memmeth as method declartion syntax?